# Save multiple images to Laravel Livewire

Tags: laravel, image, file-upload, laravel-livewire

I'm trying to save the image addresses but I get the following error: Array to string conversion Laravel.

How should I save the routes of the images? in the official documentation that point does not indicate it.

my code is the following:

**VIEW**

```
<input wire:model="imagenes" type="file" class="form-control-file" multiple>
```

**COMPONENT**

```
use WithFileUploads;
public $imagenes = [];


foreach ($this->imagenes as $pathGalería) {
       $pathGalería->store('imagenesPropiedades');
}

$properties = Property::create([

    'imagenes' => $this->imagenes

]);
```

**EDIT: ARRAY**

[image]

I get the error: Array to string conversion. Could you please help me.

Comment: Removed original comment ... `$this->imagenes` is an `Array`, that's probably where your error comes from. Doesn't your error mention a line number? I'm not familiar with Livewire so I have to ask, what are you trying to do with `Property::create()`? It's expecting a `String`, not an `Array`

Comment: If it is in: $this->imagenes Add image with array

Comment: Yes expect a string, but I need to save an array.

Comment: It won't let you save an array :) You could convert your `Array` to a `String` by using `json_encode($this->imagenes)` but I have no idea if this will work since I don't know what `Property::create` does. If needed you can convert the `String` back to an `Array`using `json_decode`. Does that help?

Comment: Hi using json_encode it saves me a single record and wrongly saves the address. **"imagenesPropiedades\/T9wElIPuG0eDol6Q8fIvPxWPVH8I7bw7zEY8UGQG.jpeg"** Maybe you know how I can first create the array in a variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I know what you are referring to. Do you mean that you want to save the hash name of the uploaded file?

For you to achieve that you should use this:

```
$properties = Property::create([
    'imagenes' => $this->imagenes->hashName()
]);
```

Alternatively, there is a youtube video series that actually covers laravel livewire simple file upload and multiple file upload features.

Simple File Upload >>> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=epf6mChMYok

Multiple File Upload >>> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nwnp3L4Oy-Q